# How do I insert a transporter into services in an Node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm a new developer and I'm setting up an app for an organization that takes donations.

I am trying to set it up where the director gets a notification whenever she gets a donation(ideally I would like this to happen both when she gets a new donation AND when she has a new donor sign up).

I got the nodemailer part to work on a mini test app to set it up correctly. Now I just need to insert it into the app in the correct place.

Right now it's firing off every time I make a change(I have all the code in the index.js file). I spoke with a senior developer about nodemailer and he mentioned one of the perks is that you can take the transporter and insert it wherever you need it.

So I'm thinking I can keep the bulk of the nodemailer code in the index.js file and put the transporter section where it needs to go. I've been playing around with placing it in different places in the services file but I clearly just don't understand the flow.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
donationcontroller.js

//create donation
router.post('/createdonation', validate, function (req, res) {
    transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log("The donation was sent!");
        console.log(info);
      });
});
```

```js
donationServices.js

//create donation
exports.createDonation = function(req, res){

    let newDonation = {
        used_clothing : 0,
        new_clothing : 0,
        used_shoes : 0,
        new_shoes : 0,
        baby_food: 0,
        diaper_bags: 0,
        bottles: 0,
        pacifiers: 0,
        diapers_boxes: 0,
        beds: 0,
        misc_items: 0
    }

    newDonation[req.body.donationOption] = req.body.donationAmount

    return donation.create(newDonation)
    .then(
        function createSuccess(donation) {
            res.json ({
                donation: donation
            });  
        },
        function createError(err){
            res.send(500, err.message);
        },

    );
}
```

```js
Index.js

// nodemailer
// houses the data to send in the email
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
  //   make true if using ssl certificate
    secure: false,
  //   stmp port
    port: 25,
    auth: {
      user: 'test.test@gmail.com',
      pass: 'password'
    },
  //   protocol
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });
  // use to construct body of email
  let HelperOptions = {
    from: '"Tester" <Test.test@gmail.com',
    to: 'test.test@gmail.com',
    subject: 'dd',
    text: 'dd'
  };
  
  // contains callback data
    transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log("The donation was sent!");
      console.log(info);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I fundamentally misunderstood your initial question when I dove into this the first time. What I should have clarified is that you absolutely do not want to use nodemailer in your Angular code. This should only be happening in your backend (Node.js), as that is the only place where your API keys or usernames/passwords will be secure from prying eyes. As soon as you put that into a frontend app, anyone can hijack your gmail account. So, keep the trigger for your emails in your backend, and you'll be in great shape. Whenever a donation is saved or whatever, just hit your backend API in some way and then you can call your `sendEmail` function. :)

**Original Post**

It looks like you probably want to put that transporter in its own module (I'm assuming `Index.js` is your top-level entry point?), so it can be more easily imported to any file. Try this:

sendEmail.js

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  //   make true if using ssl certificate
  secure: false,
  //   stmp port
  port: 25,
  auth: {
    user: 'test.test@gmail.com',
    pass: 'password'
  },
  //   protocol
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

module.exports = function ({from, to, subject, text}) {
  // Promisify it, so you can easily chain it in the wild
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // use to construct body of email
    let HelperOptions = {
      from,
      to,
      subject,
      text
    };

    // contains callback data
    transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return reject(error);
      }
      console.log("The donation was sent!");
      console.log(info);
      resolve(info);
    });
  });
};
```

Then you can use this function anywhere in your code that you want to send an email like so:

donationServices.js

```
// import the email function
const sendEmail = require('./path/to/sendEmail.js')

// create donation
exports.createDonation = function(req, res){

  let newDonation = {
    used_clothing : 0,
    new_clothing : 0,
    used_shoes : 0,
    new_shoes : 0,
    baby_food: 0,
    diaper_bags: 0,
    bottles: 0,
    pacifiers: 0,
    diapers_boxes: 0,
    beds: 0,
    misc_items: 0
  }

  newDonation[req.body.donationOption] = req.body.donationAmount

  return donation.create(newDonation)
    .then(
      function createSuccess(donation) {
        sendEmail({
          from: ‘test@gmail.com’,
          to: ‘boss@gmail.com’,
          subject: req.body.donationOption + ' donation alert'
          text: 'yay donations!\n' + JSON.stringify(donation) // you get the point...
        }).then(function (info) {
          res.json({
            donation: donation
          });
        }).catch(function (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err);
          // or maybe you don't care that the email failed:
          // res.status(200).send({message: 'donation sent, but email didn\'t'});
        }); 
      },
      function createError(err){
        res.send(500, err.message);
      }
   );
}
```

Hopefully that's clear as mud. :)

P.S. I see you might be using username/password for nodemailer authentication. From personal experience, I would strongly recommend you invest the hours to brush up on OAuth2, etc, and get that working with refresh tokens and the whole shebang. It will really be worth it and you will learn a ton in the process. Happy coding!

Comment: I'm so sorry! Sometimes I use the wrong terminology. It is an Angular app but the backend is Node.js I'll update the post title. This code is actually in the backend using Node.js. This was a group project where I worked on the backend and my team members did the frontend. They used authGuard for the frontend. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I hope this at least addressed your question in some way. Let me know if you need any clarification. :)

Comment: So now I'm getting an error:"[js] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning."

My tsconfig.json file has "experimentalDecorators" set to true. I even made a SECOND tsconfig.json file in the backend section of the code. Neither one seems to make a difference :/.

Comment: You’re getting this in Angular, or in your Node backend?

Comment: In the backend section.

Comment: Are you using typescript in your Node.js? If so, that has to be transpiled.

Comment: I should be but I know someone that's seen the whole code commented that we oscillated between typescript and regular JS. Howdy I transpile it?

Comment: Well, to be honest, you shouldn’t be using decorators in your Node.js code. Angular can do that because it is in TS and is transpiled before it actually runs in a browser. As the warning points out, decorators are only experimental in Node. Why do you want to use a decorator? Can you post the code that uses it?

Comment: I'm actually not trying to use decorators. I did some experimenting and the error pops up because of the @ symbol in the the to: and from: sections of the sendEmail function.  

It's the code you initially sent me. I'm probably making some silly mistake.

Comment: Gotcha. That worked. I knew it was something silly lol. I should have tried that.